# can a doctor write me a receipt for services rendered using a prescription slip?

Tags: receipts

I had a friend visit a doctor and he issued him a receipt for payment, written on his official little "post-it style" prescription slips.  We were laughing about it, but is it possible for doctors to use presc slips this way?

Comment: Where would you do this? In the US in many states if not all, there are no more postit-type slips, there are special secure forms, and they may be prevented by law from using the pads for other purposes. Do you mean "except where prohibited", but then it looks like you;re asking if this is a legal use in the first place. You could clarify.

Comment: Misuse of prescription slips is only a problem if it purports to be a lawful prescription and it is not. Otherwise it is just paper. @user6726 Here in Colorado we still sometimes use slips like this (at Kaiser I get them when I have an out of network prescription).

Comment: yeah, this was in New Jersey. I know we've moved to e-scripts nowadays, but i guess docs still have these old school script slips lying around. It's a full fledged presc slip like they used to make bank checkbooks with security printing and all in the past, it's got serial nos on the page etc. it's an old timer presc slip!

Answer (score 4):

### There is generally no prescribed form for a receipt

A receipt is simply evidence that money changed hands and it can be written on anything. Or recorded in a different way, say an audio file saying “I, Dave, received $100 from Jim.

There may be taxation rules about the information that needs to be in a receipt but generally not about what it’s written on.